# Парсинг BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, парсер

Всем привет!
Пожалуйста, помогите с решением парсинга текста из куска кода:

```html
<dd itemprop="value"><span class="allItemsOfLanding"><a href="/analogovye-kamery/ctv/">все аналоговые камеры CTV</a></span>CTV</dd>
```

Мне надо спарсить только значение "CTV" (содержимое тега dd), а у меня с помощью dd.getText() отдает:

```html
<span class="allItemsOfLanding"><a href="/analogovye-kamery/ctv/">все аналоговые камеры CTV</a></span>CTV
```

Т.е. лишнего хватает, не пойму как ему сказать взять значение только тега dd либо удалять в найденном dd теги span как-то.
Спасибо!

------------------ДОБАВЛЕНО----------------

Вот пример кода, который сейчас используется:

```
try:
    page_tovar = requests.get(v,headers = headers,data = data,timeout = timeout)
    soup_p = BeautifulSoup(page_tovar.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'),'lxml')
    rows_dt = soup_p.find("section",{"class":"catalog-detail-blocks"}).find("dl").findAll("dt")
    rows_dd = soup_p.find("section",{"class":"catalog-detail-blocks"}).find("dl").findAll("dd")
    result_parse_item = {}
    for i in range(0,len(rows_dt)):
        name = rows_dt[i].contents[0]  # getText()
        znach = rows_dd[i].contents[0]  # getText()
        result_parse_item[name] = znach
        result_parse[k] = result_parse_item
        print name,znach
except Exception as e:
    print " Error: {0}".format(e)
```

Comment: приведите в вопросе пример кода который сейчас используете. Возможно использовать цепочку продолжая разбор или использовать регулярное выражение, или просто поправить ваш код. Пока не ясно.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, можете посмотреть?

Comment: привел 3 варианта разбора, мне больше вариант contents нравится, но более универсальный с поиском братьев.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось, подошел первый вариант:
if len(rows_dd[i].contents) > 2:
                        znach = rows_dd[i].contents[2].strip()
                    else:
                        znach = rows_dd[i].contents[0].strip()

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае возможно использовать свойство [contents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)

```
soup.dd.contents[1]  # второй элемент, первый будет span
```

Второй вариант. Находим вначале span, от него ищем следующий элемент

```
soup.dd.find('span').next_sibling
```

третий вариант, через get_text()

```
soup.dd.get_text("|").split("|")[1]
```